# Javascript Image is not defined in QML

Tags: javascript, image, qt, qml

I would like to use `new Image()` in my QML file (Qt 5.11).
I use `import ... as` to avoid QML Image vs JS Image name clash.
But now, the resulting error on the following minimal example is:

> ReferenceError: Image is not defined

```
import QtQuick 2.11 as QQ

QQ.Canvas {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    onPaint: {
        // this is the javascript part.
        var img = new Image();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated to solve this. Do I need to install any packages on my OS (debian) for this to work?

Comment: I want to load a svg image in a Canvas. I've put the minimal code that give me this error. The 'new Image();' is not recognized.

Comment: try `var image = Image{"image.svg"}`

Comment: The problem is the Image keyword which is not recognized. With or without argument does not change the error.

Comment: try `image: {"image.svg"}`

Comment: Hum, code inside a Component.onCompleted is javascript by definition. But it doesn't seem obvious... Javascript is mentioned in the title too ;-). So, everything was here to guess.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it may be that Qt simply doesn't support js images. My understanding is that QML supports most but not all js functionality. Though trying to figure out which parts are supported is not well documented.

Comment: @JarMan, yes, it seems that Image is part of DOM, not ECMA script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to paint an image in a `Canvas` you need to use [`loadImage()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html). It will be loaded asynchronously and the canvas will emit `imageLoaded` when any new image has loaded.

You can then paint it with [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) and passing it the URL you loaded:

```
Canvas {
    property string imageUrl: "qrc://images/image.png"
    Component.onCompleted: loadImage(imageUrl)
    onImageLoaded: requestRepaint()
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(imageUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems new Image() is part of DOM, this is why I can't use it. I finally ended with your answer and a QImageProvider. My image provider takes a filename followed by a question mark and a color (`image://myimageprovider/myicon.svg?red`). I can then colorize my svg file (this is why i needed a `new Image()` ) from my image provider and print it in my canvas. Thanks you.